# 3-level nested bool queries with elasticsearch dsl

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Using ES 6.1, Python 3, and elasticsearch-dsl, I've got docs with this mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {"type": "text"},
            "prop_a": {"type": "text"},
            "prop_b": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_root": "true",
                "properties": {
                    "title": {"type": "text"},
                    "prop_bx": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {"type": "text"}
                            "descr": {"type": "text"}
                        }
                    }
```

for example:

```
{
"id": "abc123",
"prop_a": "foo",
"prop_b": { 
    "title": "some title",
    "prop_bx": {
        "name": "some name"
        "descr": "lorem ipsum ipso facto"
    }
}}
```

and I can successfully query the level 2 (prop_b) property 'title' like:

```
s1=Search().using(client).query('nested', 
    path='prop_b', 
    query=Q('match', prop_b__title='some title'))
```

I've tried many ways to get to the next level down (prop_bx), and my best shot is this, but it gets "400 failed to create query":

```
s2=Search().using(client).query('nested', 
        path='prop_b', 
        query=Q('nested',path='prop_b__propbx'),
            query=Q('match', prop_b__propbx__name='some name'))
```

Not finding answers or even clues in the docs. I can write this in the standard more verbose query form and convert with the .from_dict() method, but then why bother to convert it to elasticsearch-dsl?

Clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use . instead of __ on path:

```
S2=Search().using(client).query('nested', 
        path='prop_b.probbx', 
        query=Q('match', prop_b__propbx__name='some name'))
```